# Missing required parameters for [Route: addapplication.edit]

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble on passing application_id from application@edit controller to addapplication@index controller. Please help me.

**application@edit controller**

```
$application->application_id = $request->application_id;
              
$application->save();
              
return redirect(route('addapplication.index'))->with('application_id',$request->application_id);
```

**addapplication@index controller**

```
$application_id = Session::get('application_id');

$applications = addapplication::where('application_id', $application_id)->get();

return view('user.addapplication.index',compact('applications'));
```

**blade.php**

```
@foreach ($applications as $application)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $loop->index +1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->application_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->surname }}, {{ $application->firstname }} {{ $application->middlename }}</td>
    <td><a href = "{{ route('addapplication.edit', $application->id)}}"><img src = {{ asset('assets/img/eye.ico') }}/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: addapplication.edit] [URI:
> addapplication/{addapplication}/edit]. (View: D:\path\index.blade.php)

**here is my route.php**

```
Route::resource('application', 'ApplicationController');
Route::resource('addapplication', 'AddApplicationController');
```

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Please include the `index.blade.php` file in your question.

Comment: Please share your `route` and `blade`

Comment: Im sorry about that. I edited my question. please help me.

Comment: There is a possibility of `null` or `empty` value in `$application->id` that is used inside `route()` function. Please debug and check is there possibility of null value ?

Comment: Hi Ghanu, I returned $applications and I got results. I think I have my problem here : {{ route('addapplication.edit', $application->id)}} .. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
{{route('addapplication.edit',['addapplication'=>$application->id])}}
```

Comment: Hi, I included this to my addapplication.edit and it looks like this now : <a href = "{{ route('addapplication.edit', ['addapplication' => $application->id])}}"> but still same error. Am I doing it right?

Comment: execute this command `artisan route:list` then add your respective route in your question

Answer (score 1):

The [`route` helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L766) requires an array as the secondary argument.

```
{{ route('addapplication.edit', ['addapplication' => $application->id])}}
```

You can figure out the required key (in any scenario) by using the `artisan route:list` command and looking at the values between the curly braces in the URI column.

In your case the route should look like this:

```
/addapplications/{addapplication}/edit
```

Comment: Hi, I included this to my addapplication.edit and it looks like this now : <a href = "{{ route('addapplication.edit', ['addapplication' => $application->id])}}"> but still same error. Am I doing it right?